# Identify high-voltage power board component by its packaging and internal structure

Tags: mosfet, identification, components, packages

A component (perhaps a MOSFET) on a generator inverter board blew up. All that's left are the legs and the heat sink. Is it possible to make a good guess as to the model and the manufacturer, given the unusual packaging?

The pitch between the leads is 6 mm (at least internally). The width of the chip along the side with the leads is ~16 mm. Terminals 1 and 2 are connected. As can be seen, the heat pad/drain is gigantic.

Is there a tool from one of the large supply houses that would allow me to narrow it down based on those specs? Or is there another way to do this?

[image: board is potted; mosfet was next to the smoothing cap]

[image: closeup of the mosfet remnants]

Comment: That's just the bottom end of it. Dig more of that goo away to reveal the rest of the lead-frame. Then measure all the dimensions. This looks like a TO-247 package to me, but the measurements will tell you. Example of internal construction:- https://uspto.report/patent/app/20200303281/US20200303281A1-20200924-D00006.png

Comment: Damn bruh! That’s a significant magic smoke escaping event. Probably more things than just the transistor itself on that board and the potting mass won’t make the job of finding them easy.

Comment: @Bruce Terminals 1 and 2 are connected below, which rules out a through-hole package, since drain can only be connected electrically through the heat pad. The spacing between terminals 1 & 2 and 2 & 3 is 6mm. The total width of the component on that side is 16mm (I can tell because of a slight difference in shade between the transistor's epoxy and the potting). So this is a very large component. I'm just not familiar enough with mosfet packaging to know where to look.

Answer (score 2):

> given the unusual smd packaging of the mosfet

Looks like either a D2PAK, a TO220 (through-hole) or a TO247 (through-hole), all are incredibly common, standardized packages. Could be some other package too of course.

How do you know it was SMD? It's fairly common practice to bend the legs of a TO220/TO247 and solder its cooling pad against the PCB. The rest of the components there are likely through-hole, like those radial caps. Power electronics are often through-hole.

> Is it possible to make a good guess as to the model and the manufacturer

No.

> The pitch between the three terminal legs is 6mm

What does that even mean? Pitch = center-to-center measurement between any 2 legs. D2PAK and TO220 have pitch 0.1"/2.54mm. TO247 has pitch 5.45mm.

> Is there a tool from one of the large supply houses that would allow me to narrow it down based on those specs?

No.

> Or another way to do this?

Not really. The best way of reverse engineering this is to look at the layout and then at least try to make a qualified guess of what's drain, source and gate (I'm not sure how you even know it was a MOSFET to begin with), then at least try to narrow it down to P or N channel.

Comment: Terminals 1 and 2 are connected below, which means it can't be through-hole, since the only way to connect the drain electrically is through the heat pad.  Terminals 1 and 2 are connected to the hot wires on the generator outlets. Conventional current flows from drain to source in an N-channel, so terminal 1(and 2) is the source, terminal 4 (heat pad) is the drain. It's also the location of the channel, which I can tell by the little raised solder area on the pad. The spacing _between_ terminals 1 and 2 and _between_ 2 and 3 is 6mm.

Comment: _"Terminals 1 and 2 are connected to the hot wires on the generator outlets"_ - If this is a MOSFET then 'terminal 1' is the Source and 'terminal 2' is the Drain. It looks like 'terminal 2' is connected to 'terminal 4' (the heat sink pad) which is normal. 'Terminal 1' (Source) appears to have had two bond wires attached, but these have blown off. 6mm is consistent with TO-247 package size.

Comment: You should expose more of the package to get its full dimensions. If you are lucky part of the case may still be there with markings visible. Heating the potting compound up (eg. with a soldering iron tip) should soften it and make it easier to remove.

Comment: @BruceAbbott "Heating the potting compound up (eg. with a soldering iron tip)" Yikes, you better be using an old bad one then and not one intended for actual soldering work later.

Comment: @Bruce A hot air station softened up the potting and I was able to remove enough of the material to expose the leads. You are correct that it is a TO-247 package with bent leads. However, leads 2 and 3 (what I have labeled as terminals 1 and 2) still show 0 Ohm resistance between them. The leads are not touching anywhere where they are visible. Is there any scenario under which the drain and source of a mosfet would read continuous, or does this indicate a larger issue? Is there another semiconducting component that could be packaged in TO-247 where this would be the expected behavior?

Comment: _"Is there any scenario under which the drain and source of a mosfet would read continuous"_ - No. But it might not even be a MOSFET. Inverter generators also have diodes and IGBTs. https://generators.smps.us/inverter-generator.html Perhaps something else is shorted. I suggest removing all the epoxy and tracing the circuit, then you can figure out what the reading should be and what else might be wrong.

Comment: Continued removing the potting, and it turned out that the circuit consists of 4 or 5 of these mosfets in parallel. The printing was visible on the second one I uncovered. It is https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/158215/RENESAS/FS50SM-5A.html N-Channel mosfet. All 4 of the ones I've uncovered so far are shorted, with the gate, source and drain reading continuous. That's why the exploded mosfet showed continuity between drain and source despite no visible contact.

Comment: Given this kind of catastrophic damage to the mosfets, any chance the gate driver circuitry might still be intact, with the power mosfets taking the brunt of the impact?